# Can I make the pytest doctest module ignore a file?

Tags: python, pytest, doctest

We use pytest to test our project and have enabled `--doctest-modules` by default to collect all of our doctests from across the project.

However there is one `wsgi.py` which may not be imported during test collection, but I cant get pytest to ignore it.

I tried putting it in the `collect_ignore` list in `conftest.py` but apparently the doctest module does not use this list.

The only thing that does work is putting the whole directory of `wsgi.py` into `norecursedirs` in the pytest config file, but this obviously hides the whole directory, which I don't want.

Is there a way to make the doctest module ignore just a certain file?

Comment: This may be helpful https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/pythoncollection.html

Answer (score 8):

As [MasterAndrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41374309/4731718) has mentioned, `pytest_ignore_collect` should do the trick. Important to note that you should put `conftest.py` to root folder (the one you run tests from).
Example:

```
import sys

def pytest_ignore_collect(path):
    if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
        if str(path).endswith("__py2.py"):
            return True
    else:
        if str(path).endswith("__py3.py"):
            return True
```

Since pytest v4.3.0 there is also `--ignore-glob` flag which allows to ignore by pattern. Example:
`pytest --doctest-modules --ignore-glob="*__py3.py" dir/`

Comment: The crucial part for me was to put this `pytest_ignore_collect` hook in a conftest.py in the *root* of the project. We had a conftest.py in our `tests` directory with several settings, and placing the hook there did not work.

Comment: hmmm ... this just gives me a whole load of `E   KeyError: '--doctest-modules'`

Answer (score 6):

You can use hook to conditionally exclude some folders from test discovery.
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html

```
def pytest_ignore_collect(path, config):
    """ return True to prevent considering this path for collection.
    This hook is consulted for all files and directories prior to calling
    more specific hooks.
    """
```